# Multiple views/activities controlling CastButton

Tags: java, android, oop, design-patterns, chromecast

If we look at a bunch of Chromecast Apps, we see that the cast button persists across different views/activities. That is, when we connect to chromecast in the main activity, and later enter a videoplayer activity, the cast button is still available.

Programmatically, what is the best design for this desired behavior? All I can think of is to first start detecting the existing chromecast devices available in the main activity, and keep passing this cast button as a parameter to other classes in which we need to show a cast button in. Would this work? or would we essentially have a lot of duplicate code in different classes? How are you guys designing your cast apps with this desired behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

You do not pass around cast button between activities, etc. Either your application is basically just one activity with multiple fragments, in which case you don't have any issue, or if it has multiple activities, each activity adds the cast button to its action bar; the preferred version is to use the ActionProvider version but that is not required. The more important thing is that if you have multiple activities, you want to keep the states related to cast outside of each individual activity; so using a, say, singleton, to maintain the state is a good approach.

I also recommend you take a look at the [CastCompanionLibrary](https://github.com/googlecast/CastCompanionLibrary-android) (CCL) and try to use that library to build your cast application (or to add cast functionality to your existing app) since that library takes care of a number of important cast related tasks for you.

Comment: Thanks. So assuming that we have one activity(No actionbar) with multiple fragments. Would we still use the singleton approach to maintain state between the cast buttons in different fragmentActivities? I guess my other question would be, as long as one of my activities extends either the ActionBarActivity or FragmentActivity, I would be able to add chromecast support without needing to build a custom cast button in my app? since we can simply maintain the state using the singleton approach between different classes AND adding a cast button can happen in any view?

Comment: For the first question, I am a bit confused since you mentioned one activity but then you talk about "..cast buttons in different fragmentActivities"? FragmentActivity is an activity so what did you mean by one activity and multiple FragmentActivities? As for the second part, maintaining state is an internal thing to your app and as long as you have different "pages" in your application (whether that amounts to one activity with multiple fragments or multiple activities), it is very important to have the cast button visible on all pages.

Comment: I meant to say one activity and a bunch of other views that do not extend either the ActionBarActivity or FragmentActivity. Would a class that extends a linear layout be able to show a cast button? or would you always need to extend either of the two classes if you want to display a button? I was under the impression that mMediaRouterButton.setVisible(View.Visible) can happen anywhere as long as you've added MRB to your layouts..